# Como configurar cronjobs no cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cron

Como faço para usar o cronjobs no CakePHP, preciso chamar uma action de um controller no servidor linux, é o caminho do script?

Já tentei aqui e não deu certo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O ideal é você fazer isto na sua camada de `Model`, acho que você deve repensar esta sua opção em chamar diretamente do `Controller`.

Para isso, você primeiro deve criar uma [**task shell**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell), que será executada no agendador de tarefas do seu servidor. Vamos supor que você queira limpar uma tabela *photos* a cada meia-hora, então você cria uma task a partir de um arquivo `app/Console/Command/PhotoShell.php` mais ou menos assim:

```
class PhotoShell extends AppShell {
    public function limpar() {
        ClassRegistry::init('Photo')->limpar();
    }
}
```

E seu *model* `Photo` teria o método `limpar()` implementado assim:

```
public function limpar() {
    $this->query('TRUNCATE ' . $this->useTable);
}
```

Pronto, feito isto, basta incluir no seu *cronjobs*:

```
0,30 * * * * /app/Console/cake Photo limpar
```

Lembrando que o arquivo **cake** deve estar com as devidas permissões de execução.

Comment: Paulo, vou seguir suas dicas e efetuar as mudanças, valeu!!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do próprio cakebook

```
  */5  *    *    *    *  cd /full/path/to/app && Console/cake myshell myparam
  # *    *    *    *    *  command to execute
  # │    │    │    │    │
  # │    │    │    │    │
  # │    │    │    │    \───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday,
    |    |    |    |           or use names)
  # │    │    │    \────────── month (1 - 12)
  # │    │    \─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
  # │    \──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
  # \───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html

Comment: Eu já tinha visto este link mas não tinha entendido, da forma como o @PauloRodrigues explicou, ficou fácil.